# Tell don't ask -- how does it apply to this example?

Tags: encapsulation, tell-dont-ask

As a proxy for something real I am working on, consider building a model. We'd have a `Parts` class representing model parts, complete with methods to manufacture the part based on given parameters, to validate, etc. We have a `Glue` class which does much the same, and a `ModelBuilder` class.

I can manufacture my glue and parts with nice encapsulation. Then I pass my `PartsInstance` and my `GlueInstance` to my `ModelBuilder` as parameters. Here's where everything falls apart. I can tell my ModelBuilder to build, but to do so, it needs access to the data in the `Parts` (and maybe the `Glue`). I may for instance need to know where the corner or center of `PartsInstance.Part[0]` is in order to properly build.

I'm in a quandary here because it seems the Tell, Don't Ask camp would say that the part should build itself somehow. But that doesn't make sense to me. A part is a part, not the whole model. That's what should build itself. The `ModelBuilder` could be quite complex, and it's possible that the `Parts` might be used somewhere else. On the other hand, I'm inquiring as to the state of the `PartsInstance` object and then making a decision based on that state. Furthermore, the decision may not be something that fits solely inside the `Parts` concept anyway. It may involve the type of `Glue` I've chosen.

How can I construct or rework this example so that it doesn't violate encapsulation?

Comment: Why does the ModelBuilder need to know where the corner of a part is?